# SQL many-to-many design

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

OK, so I will probably get slaughtered for being lazy and not researching this myself - but I just can't get my head around it and it is making my brain hurt. And I am sure for some of you guys out there it is a pretty basic problem.

I have one Excel table with football (soccer) players and their attributes...

[Player Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyrrR.jpg)

and another with six-a-side football (soccer) teams, with six players in six positions.

[Teams Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpb0f.jpg)

I want to be able to link the two tables so that I can make aggregate team attributes based on the player attributes and then run queries on the qualities of the teams (i.e. best passing teams, most aggresive teams etc).

In Excel I would just do a vlookup from the player table into the teams table and then add up various combinations of the attributes of the players.

However in SQL it seems complicated - i.e. each team has many players, any one player can be in more than one team and any one player can play in a number of different positions. Which position the player plays in affects the weighting it contributes to the team attributes (i.e. a defender would contribute less to the teams creativity than an attacking midfielder, and more to the teams tackling ability than a forward). I think I need an intermediate join table or maybe several? Or maybe it is just simple after all?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

thankyou

Ben

Comment: Holy wall of text please at least provide sample data or make your question more concise.

Comment: To answer what I think the question is "intermediate join table(s)", yes that should the trick. Which at least to me is less complicated than not using them for these types of relationships.

Comment: thank you @John K... I now have a way forward - and I have also found out how I can illustrate the data on this site. :0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get your question, the answer is the following. You will have a table for players (PlayerID, PlayerName, PlayerAtribbute1,...), a table for the teams (TeamId, TeamName, HomeTown,...) and an intermediate table for the connection of the two (PlayerId, TeamId, Position,...). The last intermediate table is used in SQL and database design to represent many-to-many relationships.

If you go with this approach, you should also index PlayerId in the Players table, TeamID in the Teams table and have a composite index on (PlayerId, TeamID) in the intermediate table and you should be golden.

Comment: Thank you @S Karras, I think what I was not getting my head around is the composite index of player_ID and team_ID. So there will be a line in the intermediate table for every combination of player and team, which also states the position they play for that particular team. I have something to work with now... my next step is to go investigate whether I can automate the creation of the join table from Excel - it would be painful to input each line manually.

Comment: ... and I think I can maybe import this from Excel, using the concatenated IDs and other relevant columns.

Comment: I am glad I could help! I know it is a little weird to ask, but can you upvote my answer or set it as a verified answer for your question?

Comment: No problem @S Karras I have upvoted - you should not need to ask - I'm not sure if it will register until I gain more reputation points though.

Comment: Thanks! If you tried to accept the answer as well, maybe it would show then.

Comment: You sir are awesome! Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

The missing piece in the jigsaw in my mind was the composite index in the join table (provided by S Karras). I can now take this forward and see how it progresses.